siunitx wrongly typesets asymmetric uncertainty with zero value
In engineering drawings it is not uncommon to specify asymmetric tolerance where one value is zero. However, these tolerance are wrongly typeset by siunitx package. Note that one typically does not write the sign for the zero value. As seen in the MWE the option retain-zero-uncertainty doesn't fix it.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty, retain-zero-uncertainty]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    siunitx output: \num{10(0:1)} \\
    expected output: $10^{\phantom{-}0}_{-1}$
\end{document}



Could you please specify where such an output is used in publications? I have never seen that before

It's called a unilateral tolerance and is very common in mechanical engineering

is there an article or something you can link? might be useful to see the context. is there an iso standard for this format?

The rules are described in EN ISO 129-1 standard in section 6.2 Limit deviations

Looks like a bug to me ({1:0} works), so report it at https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues
